Help identify ICs with markings 'B157' 'B153F'
I can't find any information about these ICs (presumably transistors) on a ASRock IMB-170:

B157
B153F

I did replace with 6Kbba. It works but it has very low mA whenever I install PCIe graphics card the 12V drops to 9.8V and graphics card won't boot.



Please, check this one NTM2222A.


